# How to add elements into a LinkedList without them changing during compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a C# code on Visual Studio. I've created a LinkedList<"T"> (called 'data') and a temporary variable of type T (lets call it 'temp'). the variable properties of temp always changes during compilation, and at certain junctions, I add it to the list as follows. 
 `data.addLast(temp);` 
 I originally expect `data` to have a list of different values, but it only captures multiple copies of the final value of `temp`. I don't intend to change the variable `data` to an array. How can I get the list to produce values in the way I expect it to?

Edit: Alright, I apologize in advance for sounding a bit too abstract but here goes 
 `

```
public class Obj { 
    public String name; 
}
```

and here's my main class:

```
   LinkedList<Obj> data = new LinkedList<Module>(); 
    Obj temp = new Obj(); 
    temp.name = "ABC"; 
    data.AddLast(temp); 
    temp.name = "DEF"; 
    data.AddLast(temp);
```

`

When I print the `name` property for each element in `data`, both produce "DEF". I can't understand as to why though.

Comment: Read about value types and reference types. You are working with a reference type

Comment: Lovely question. However this is a site for programming and as such we  usually expect to see code to answer questions. It makes it a whole lot easier

Comment: Yes, I've added some code into my question. Hopefully this makes it easier to visualize.

Comment: Side note: we almost never use LinkedList<>. Be very sure you need fast insert in the middle or use a List<> .

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy object and modified that if you want to not affect original object. Class objects are reference typed so, - `MyClass temp = originalObject;` - temp and originalObject actually point to the same memory address. Hence; It does not matter changing temp or originalObject property.

I code small example according to your case, I hope it helps.

```
class Program
{
   public class Obj
   {
       public String name;

       public Obj Clone()
       {
           return this.MemberwiseClone() as Obj;
       }
   }
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       LinkedList<Obj> data = new LinkedList<Obj>();
       Obj temp = new Obj();
       temp.name = "ABC";
       data.AddLast(temp);
       Obj tempCopy = temp.Clone();
       tempCopy.name = "DEF";
       data.AddLast(tempCopy);

       foreach (Obj myClass in data)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(myClass.name);
       }

       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation on reference and value types clears up a lot of the confusion for me. Just to clarify, the clone() method returns a value type to the assigned variable right?

Comment: A simple `new` would be much preferred over Clone() though.

Comment: Clone() not return value type. It also return class object and it is still reference type. Clone work like that create `new` object and copy your originalObject property to your new clone object. If you change most of object's property, clone operation is over costly and this point I prefer create `new` object (At this point I am aggree with @HenkHolterman ). If your object has multiple property and you change some of them. `Clone` operation give simplicity.

Comment: Yes, the objects I'm intending to work with contain some properties that I will be changing frequently throughout runtime. Interesting to see a new declaration method that you introduced here though!

Comment: I am glad to help :)